How to change default mathjax renderer?
How to change the default renderer from HTML-CSS to Common-HTML? HTML-CSS displays a mess on my computer. Any method is fine, extensions, scripts, etc. Specifically, only setting up the math stackexchange website would be good enough; I rarely use Mathjax elsewhere.

Does this answer your question? How do I change Math Renderer for MathJax? - found using a site search. Note there are also other related questions, e.g., How to change the default MathJax renderer on Math.SE? (although that one's where the choice didn't stick).

No I want that every time when I open websites the render is automatically changed, but not every time I have to switch
